# how to another url in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery. I want to call a jsp page from jquery.
In javascript i used as,

```
  $("#submit").click(function(){
         var spid=$('#heading').text();
         window.open('salesplanvalidation.jsp?salespersonid='+spid,target='_self');
   });
```

In jquery it is not working. If i removed the target option then it is working 
but the new jsp page is loading into another tab 
and the parameter **salespersonid** is not passing there. What i have to do now??

Comment: Are you just trying to go to an url using javascript?

Comment: you accidentally a word in the title...

Comment: jQuery doesn't override standard 'window' javascript variable. I should work. Another option could be setting 'window.location'

Answer (score 2):

How about redirecting the user to the new page using the `location` object:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var spid=$('#heading').text();
    location = 'salesplanvalidation.jsp?salespersonid='+spid
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to open it in your current tab, use this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var spid = $('#heading').text();
    window.location = 'salesplanvalidation.jsp?salespersonid=' + spid;
});
```

However, if you want to open it in a new tab, use this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var spid = $('#heading').text();
    window.open('salesplanvalidation.jsp?salespersonid=' + spid);
});
```

Comment: But it is showing null on String salesperson=request.getParameter("salespersonid"); at salesplanvalidation.jsp page??